# reactjs : unable to map over state due to it being undefined/ error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm unable to map over my state, pass down into my grandchild `EmailDetails`. I'am able to console log it up to until I try to map the urls array in the render function of `EmailDetails`.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import IssueBox from "./issuebox.js";
    import "./App.css";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          isLoaded: false,
          emails: [],
          counter: 0,
          title: "Test run",
          value: "",
          selectedEmailId: 0,
          currentSection: "inbox"
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch("blah")
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(result => {
            const emails = result.data;
            console.log("resutl state: ", emails);
            let id = 0;
            for (const email of emails) {
              email.id = id++;
            }
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              emails: emails
            });
          });
      }

      handleClickReproducibleCounter(e) {
        let count = this.state.increment
          ? this.state.count + 1
          : this.state.count - 1;

        let increment = this.state.increment;

        if (count === 0) {
          increment = true;
        } else if (count >= 2) {
          increment = false;
        }

        this.setState({
          count,
          increment
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <div>
              emails={this.state.emails}
              selectedEmailId={this.state.selectedEmailId}
              onEmailSelected={id => {
                this.openEmail(id);
              }}
              handleClickReproducibleCounter={this.handleClickReproducibleCounter}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

// data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    groupID: "65da6a",
    urls: [
      {
        id: 85,
        searchedurl: "https://www.yahoo.com",
        errorurl: "https://www.yahoo.com/error505",
        count: 1,
        reproducible: false,
        reproducible_counter: 0
      },
      {
        id: 84,
        searchedurl: "https://www.gmail.com",
        errorurl: "https://www.gmail.com/error404",
        count: 1,
        reproducible: false,
        reproducible_counter: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupID: "d4127e",
    urls: [
      {
        id: 3,
        searchedurl: "agwscc",
        errorurl: "xyqa",
        count: 1,
        reproducible: false,
        reproducible_counter: 0,
        resolved: null
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

//issuebox.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import EmailDetails from "./emailDetails";

class IssueBox extends Component {
  constructor(args) {
    super(args);
  }

  render() {

    const currentEmail = this.props.emails.find(
      x => x.id === this.props.selectedEmailId
    );
    console.log("emailDetail view: ", currentEmail); // email obj is present

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="inbox-container">
          <EmailList
            emails={this.props.emails}
            onEmailSelected={this.props.onEmailSelected}
            selectedEmailId={this.props.selectedEmailId}
          />

          <EmailDetails
            email={currentEmail} 
            onReproducibleCounter={this.props.handleClickReproducibleCounter}
            onValidateSumbit={this.props.handleClickValidateSumbission}
            handleTextInputChange={this.props.handleTextInputChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IssueBox;
```

// EmailDetails

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class EmailDetails extends Component {
  constructor(args) {
    super(args);

    this.state = {
      counter: "",
      email: []
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.email !== prevProps.email) {
      this.setState({ email: this.props.email });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const currentEmail = this.state.email;
    console.log(currentEmail, this.state.email.urls); // able to console obj
    const test = this.state.email.urls.map(obj => {
      //error occurs here
      console.log(obj);
    });
    return (
      <div className="email-content">
        <div className="email-content__header">
          <h3 className="email-content__subject">Issue</h3>
          <div className="email-content__from">Group:</div>
        </div>
        <div className="email-content__message">
          <table role="table">
            <thead role="rowgroup">
              <tr role="row">
                <th role="columnheader">Searched URL</th>
                <th role="columnheader">Error URL</th>
                <th role="columnheader">NR</th>
                <th role="columnheader">Task</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody role="rowgroup" className="group-row" />
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EmailDetails;
```

Used this on as my starting point: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwdbBJ)

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it and which line causes it?

Comment: I do get an error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` inside of EmailDetails in the render function when I call this.state.email.urls.map()

Comment: That line of code doesn't appear anywhere in what you posted here. Please [edit] your code to show it. Also, show an example value for `this.state.email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to write a comment but it got longer, so I decided to provide an answer instead.

It is a little bit hard to follow your code but there are some problems I see and a few things that I don't understand.

Firstly, you are not binding your `handleClickReproducibleCounter` in `App`. So, you can't use `this` for callback functions. Either bind it in your constructor or use an arrow function instead.

```
handleClickReproducibleCounter = (e) => {
...
}
```

Secondly, you are using this function in your `EmailDetails` component like:

```
<button onClick={this.props.onReproducibleCounter(obj.id)}>
```

Why are you using `this.props`? There is no need for `this`, also you are destructing the `onReproducibleCounter` from props already. Also, you are not using a callback for `onClick` handler here, immediately invoking the function with an argument and this is not the what you actually want.

So, it should be like this:

```
<button onClick={() => onReproducibleCounter(obj.id)}>
```

Though, using an arrow function or binding the functions in JSX props is not so good, since they are recreated in every render. But, in your situation, it is a little bit tricky to change this logic. You are passing a prop to a child component and map some stuff there. The easy way is, map in the parent, then pass the single item to the child component.

Now, the things I did not understand. You are passing some `obj.id` to your callback but waiting for `e`? And it seems you are not using this argument anywhere in your function.

The second thing that I don't understand is in your map you are using a second argument as `onReproducibleCounter`

```
email.urls.map((obj, onReproducibleCounter) => {
```

The Second parameter is `index` here.

**Update after comments**

You are fetching this data in the parent with an async job. When you try to map over `this.state.email.urls`, at that time there are no `this.state.email.urls` then you get an error.

Just use conditional rendering or logging, whatever you want.

```
(this.state.email.urls || [] ).map(obj => {
      //error occurs here
    console.log(obj);
});
```

So, if there is no `email.urls` then our map will use an empty array which is OK for us. After fetch completed and the component will be re-rendered, it will map the real data.

But, do not compy your props into child's state. Use the `email` prop there. If you need to do something with it, do it in your child component.

Here is a very simple and stupid example:

```js
const Child = (props) => {
  const doSomething = () => {
    const newNumber = props.number * 20;
    props.handleNumber( newNumber );
  }
  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={doSomething}>Click me, so do something in the Child and change this number.</button>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    number: 10,
  }

  handleNumber = number => this.setState({number});

  render() {
    return <div>
    <p>Number is: {this.state.number}</p>
    <Child number={this.state.number} handleNumber={this.handleNumber} />
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my errors. I did get lost there. I have a follow up question: There is brief delay where it register my logs as `undefined undefined` before populating it, which lifecycle hook should I use?

Comment: You are welcome. Are you asking for `email.urls.map`? If so, I am going to update my answer.

Comment: I've added a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding what you're asking, when you pass callbacks like this to children you need to make sure that the `this` keyword is pointed at the correct thing.

The easiest way to do this is with [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) functions so

```
 handleClickReproducibleCounter(e) {
```

becomes

```
 handleClickReproducibleCounter = e => {
```

You can also accomplish this in your `constructor` function by adding a line that says

```
this.handleClickReproducibleCounter = this.handleClickReproducibleCounter.bind(this)
```

What this does is ensure that when `handleClickReproducibleCounter` is called, `this.state` always refers to the state of your parent component (or to whichever component it is bound to).

As far as your question:

> Does that mean I need to keep track of a separate state in the grandchild?

Correct, you do not need to. You can pass callbacks down as far as you'd like as long as they are properly bound to your parent components state and you will be able to alter that state from wherever you need to in your app.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my errors! I've decide to make `EmailDetails` as a component so that I could store the state changes that I captured from the user and then use a callback function passed down from the parent component `App` to then update the state there (increment/decrement of count and inputed text of users name). Is this approach correct or could I've done it without storing extra state in `EmailDetails`.

Comment: No, don't write your code like that. React is unidirectional, you get props from the parent, do something in child and pass back the data with a callback function again where you get from your parent. So, you won't copy any state, even you won't keep any state in the child.